# Can Storage Spaces be used for Hyper-V VMs?

Tags: windows, hyper-v, windows-server-2012, storage-spaces

I'm planning to update my server from Win Server 2008 Rs to 2012 when it is released. 
I'm very interested in the new "Storage Spaces". 
The main question I have is whether I can mount a storage space into a Hyper-V VM directly (like I can with physical disks in the current version)

Unfortunately I have no hardware to test it on at the moment and I can't test that in a VM (Hyper-V can't install inside a Hyper-V VM) and I could not find a definite answer on the internet either.

Has anyone of you tested such a setup?

Comment: when you say "Hyper-V VM directly" do you mean as a passthru disk?

Comment: yes, that's what I meant to say

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you could mount it into a VM as a pass-through disk.  But what would that get you?  You'd have a VM that's not portable, not able to migrate, not able to snapshot, not able to back up.

You'd be much better off putting a VHDX file on that space and mounting that in the VM.  And, though this might not be your response, most people I've had this conversation with immediately countered, saying that they didn't want the performance overhead of the VHD.  I challenge you to measure it.  See if you can find any meaningful difference between pass-through disks and VHDX files.

Comment: the thing about vhd vs passthru is that you could have 20 vms running off one lun thus performance will be impacted. So if you want more consistent performance use passthru.

Comment: A storage space is no more separate from the underlying storage than a VHD is.  It's just some storage taken from a bunch of underlying LUNs.  Tony, are you just arguing that it's easier to lose track of managing your storage with VHDs?  I might buy that.  But it seems easier to just say that if you want dedicated performance, you need to make sure that you're not sharing with the wrong workloads, which you can do with VHD files almost as easily.

Comment: I think you may be confusing native boot vhd performance vs vhd's on shared media. The more vm's you have on a lun the less performance you'll have.  I've never seen a ms doc that disputes this.

Comment: No, I'm not confusing them, and I don't dispute that.  But you could say just as usefully, the more Spaces you have spread across a few physical LUNs the less performance you'll have.  A VHD file and a Storage Space are really much more alike than they are different.  They both take a bunch of storage extents from an underlying media and present a virtual disk interface.  They both can be the only virtual disk on that underlying media or they both can share it.

Comment: ok we are arguing about different things here, extract storage spaces from the argument and concentrate on your statement "saying that they didn't want the performance overhead of the VHD. I challenge you to measure it. See if you can find any meaningful difference between pass-through disks and VHDX files." its easily measurable once you go beyond a single vhd per lun.

Comment: Tony, I understand your point.  I don't think you understand mine.  Sharing LUNs isn't the "overhead" of a VHD.  And Spaces don't necessarily have the physical LUN to themselves.  If Apollo thinks that Spaces will give him better performance than VHDs, he's probably wrong.  If you (or anyone else) thinks that dedicating physical storage to a VM will increase the performance, or at least the predictability of a VM, you're right.  But nobody is contesting that.

Comment: Well my concern really wasn't performance but flexibility. There is more than one VM running on that machine and I do not want to assign certain physical disks to certain VMs but I still want to be able to access the data on the disks in the case there should be a problem with the VM. If I use VHD(X)s on the host side, I have a single file (the VHD file) that mighjt contain large amounts of data, which make it hard to move it to, for example other disks

Comment: It's actually far easier to do those things with a VHD file than with a Storage Space.  Files can be moved and/or copied.  Spaces can't.

Comment: yeah, but a VHD might be get several TBs big whiches makes copying them a little more complicated

Comment: @apollo Why not create separate LUNs per VHDs, and put one dynamic VHD in there. That way your VHDs remain small and copyable, but they won't get fragmented like "multiple VHDs on a single LUN" would.

Comment: @Apollo God forbid network share/mapped drive...

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure the answer would be that if you used the storage pool as an iscsi target then yes otherwise no.

Comment: with 2012 smb3 you can host vhd's but they won't be passthru.

Comment: darn was thinking of connecting to a remote storage pool not local!